# Output response from closed loop transfer function using MATLAB

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, matlab, inverse-function, inverse-laplace

This transfer function is to control the position of Permanent Magnet DC motor. I was able to get the transfer function and now I need to analyze the output for the tuned closed loop for a given input function. [image: Closed Loop Transfer Function]

To solve this problem, my solution was cross multiply the equation and take the inverse Laplace transformation and after solve it as a differential equation. So I've written a MATLAB code and that MATLAB code gives me an error message. Can anyone help me to identify my error in the code or the way I've chosen to solve this problem?

MATLAB Code

```
t = 0:0.0001:1/180;
kp = 10;
kd = 1.3;
eqn ='0.00072*D3x+0.07206*D2x+(0.7274*kd+0.44244)*Dx+0.7274*kp*x=(0.7274*kd*Dt+0.7274*kp*t)*60*t';
inits = 'x(0)=0,Dx(0)=60,D2x(0)=0,t(0)=0';
x = dsolve(eqn,inits,'t');
z = eval(vectorize(x));
plot(t,z),grid on
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: Please use Mathjax (similar to LaTeX) and type your transfer function into the question. You can click edit at my answer and copy the Mathjax piece for the transfer function and use it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the capabilities of MATLAB correctly.

I will give an example. You can define the transfer function (from [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/examples/plotting-system-responses.html))

$$G(s) = \dfrac{8s^2+2s+32}{3s^3+6s^2+14s+24}$$

by the following line in MATLAB

```
sys = tf([8 2 32],[3 6 14 24]).
```

Then you can get the system responses by

```
subplot(2,1,1)
step(sys)    % step response
subplot(2,1,2)
impulse(sys) % impulse response
```

or use an arbitrary time input (e.g. $\sin(10 t)$)

```
t = 0:0.01:4;
u = sin(10*t);
lsim(sys,u,t)   % u,t define the input signal
```

**EDIT**: Constructing piecewise defined functions. In order to define the piecewise function

$$f(t) = 
\begin{cases}
f_1(t)&\quad \text{, for } t \leq t_1 \\
f_2(t)&\quad \text{, for } t_1 < t \leq t_2\\
f_3(t)&\quad \text{, for } t_2 < t \leq t_3\\
f_4(t) &\quad \text{, for } t_3 < t 
\end{cases}$$

we can use the [Heaviside step function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/heaviside.html). In your case $f_4(t)=0$. You can construct your input as

```
u = f_1(t) + [f_2(t) - f_1(t)] * heaviside(t-t_1) + [f_3(t) - f_2(t)] * heaviside(t - t_2) + [f_4(t) - f_3(t)] * heaviside(t - t_3)
```

Comment: Actually, my input is quite complex. it is v(t) = 60*t for 0<t<1/180, v(t) = 1/3 for 1/180 < t < 3601/180 and v(t) = -60*t for 3601/180 < t < 3602/180. I need to analyse the continuous function. can you give me a hint?

Comment: @wika: I added an explanation of how you can get piecewise inputs. BTW I think your $v(t)$ for the last interval is wrong because the function is not continuous at $t=3601/180$.

Comment: @wika: I do not have a MATLAB copy to check if my proposed solution helps.

Comment: Thank you very much